# What methods can I use to growl from the command line in OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, command-line, osx-lion, growl

In OS X Snow Leopard I used the `growlnotify` utility that was included in the `Growl 1.2 SDK`. I've downloaded the SDK for Growl 1.3 but I don't see any `growlnotify` utility included (am I missing it?)

Growl 1.3 also supports `GNTP`, which I have not yet used, however OS X (all versions) have support for many languages such as `php, ruby, perl, python,` etc. and I have heard that there are some good GNTP libraries out there.

**So what methods can I use to growl from the command line in OS X Lion?**

Examples are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`growlnotify` is a Growl extra.
You need to install it separately:

http://growl.info/extras.php#growlnotify

Comment: excellent. thanks. i was able to find it on this page http://growl.info/downloads#generaldownloads today but i swear i couldn't find it on the growl site the other day.